# SVG flashing large while screen draws

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a 'standard' web masthead logo snippet that I use with an SVG logo by preference, the code goes like this;

```
<div class="site-branding">
  <a id="logo" href="/">
    <img src="/pathto/logo.svg">
  </a>
</div>
```

The size of the various components are controlled by CSS.

The issue I have is that, while the page renders, the SVG draws first so that it flashes full width before the CSS for the containers constrain it. It seems as if SVG, as XML without size information, gets rendered before an image and by default is the full width of the viewport. If I use a PNG it has inherent size information so is not affected in the same way.

It's not usually a problem, and certainly not after a page is cached but on a slow connection can be obvious and ugly. Even on a faster connection there is often a flash of a larger image.

What do I need to do to prevent this behaviour? It should be said that hard-coding the size of the `img` tag is my least favourite option.

Comment: A couple things... Is your stylesheet linked in the `<head>`? Do you have access to the SVG file, and if so can you add a `width` and `height` attribute to the actual `<svg>` element?

Comment: sorry, forgot to return. Yes, the stylesheet is in the head. I'll try adding the `width` and `height`, `viewport` makes no difference

Comment: I've started using the attribute width, it means a bit of hard coding for presentation but hey-ho, it works